# check multiple values exists php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP

```
$permission = array( "admin", "moderator", "guest"  );
```

and i have another array

```
$userRoles = array( "admin", "moderator" );
```

I checked with `in_array` but it doesn't work with multiple values.

How can i check atleast one value in `$userRoles` exists on `$permission` without looping ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
count(array_intersect($permission, $userRoles));
```

Comment: There's not need to call count() unless you really need the count.   You can just use `if (array_intersect($permission, $userRoles)) ...`.

Answer (score 14):

Use `array_intersect`

> **array_intersect** — Computes the intersection of arrays
>
> array `array_intersect ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $ ... ] )`
>
> **array_intersect()** returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

**<kbd>[`Read`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)</kbd>**

Comment: @Red thanks buddy...i just do not want giving solution but also want to make you learn.