# check in array if array contains a value in php

Tags: php

I have a input phone number 489998723(filled by user).
And form database I get following prefixes with rate in array

```
4899981
4899
4899988
489998
4899987
48999
```

How I will perform the exact match.
Example User entered `489998723` than it should match by `4899987`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check multiple values exists php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515560/check-multiple-values-exists-php-array)

Comment: use array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = false ] )

Comment: Why would you want a loose match on a phone number?

Comment: Hi, because according to these prefixes rate will be change for 489998 calling rate will be.023 and 4899987 calling rate will be .58

Comment: So... you've definitely declared an array with these numbers as keys and rates as values, right?  I didn't see it in the question details.

Comment: Why don't you do the matching when you query the database? `WHERE '489998723' LIKE CONCAT(prefix, '%')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest to use [str_pos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$phone = 489998723;

$arr = [
    4899981,
    4899,
    4899988,
    489998,
    4899987,
    48999,
];


rsort($arr);

$result = false;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    // First match will be string of max length because of sorting
    if (strpos(strval($phone), strval($value)) === 0) {
        $result = $value;
        break;
    }
}

if ($result) {
    print_r ('result: ' . $result . PHP_EOL);
} else {
    print_r ('not found' . PHP_EOL);
}
```

[Sandbox code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47d441ee080c8a296e29a5f31aae130ea3871c7b)

Comment: Thanks A.Mikhailov It works perfectly. Thank You very much